# import sun.security.pkcs11 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import, pkcs#11

I'm updating a code from Java8 to Java11 and eclipse is not recognizing these packages:

```
import sun.security.pkcs11.*; 
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.*;
```

> The error is "The package is not acessible"

But the package is available in JDK

```
module jdk.crypto.cryptoki {
    // Depends on SunEC provider for EC related functionality
    requires jdk.crypto.ec;

    provides java.security.Provider with sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11; }
```

I tryed to add this line to maven args without success

```
<arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since Java 9 the system library is now modularized. Only the packages exported by a module are accessible. This is why you get the error. Your conclusion that Eclipse does not recognize these packages is wrong (the error message is `The package ... is not accessible`, not `The import ... cannot be resolved`). Instead, `SunPKCS11` is provided as a service. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html

Comment: Did you found any solution to use SUNPKCS11 wrapper in jdk 14

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I switched to JRE instead JDK in the build path.

As far as I know it is because JRE has the security policies.

Comment: The issue is to do with module imports, not JDK/JRE